# Finding and coloring countries based on latitude/longitude in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have three points (with latitude/longitude and population) located in three different countries.

How can I know which country each point belongs to automatically in ArcGIS desktop 10.2?

What steps should I follow?

Second, I want to color the country retrieved as red if the population is bigger than 10 million, as yellow if it is below 10 million but bigger than 1 million; as red if smaller than 1 million.

What steps and tools should I use?

I have downloaded the world country boundaries.

I have a series of points (lat,lon, attribute value). In arcgis desktop 10.2,

1. How to automatically retrieve the countries those points fall in?
2. What is the best way to color the country one point falls in and with the attribute value > threshold?

I can find answers using google chart. But it would be better if I can do it in ArcGIS.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) to get values from one to the other.

Then you can read about [Displaying Layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/About_displaying_layers/00s50000001s000000/) to color by attribute.